# Get values from an xml file with python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, elementtree

**Context:**

I want to obtain information from an xml file. when doing print

"<Element 'vocation' at 0x000001C9C7849040>" I do not want that message to appear but the value

Original file XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<spells>
<instant name="spell 1">
<vocation name="men 50"/>
<vocation name="men 100"/>
</instant>

    
<instant name="spells 2">
<vocation name="woman 50"/>
<vocation name="woman 100"/>
</instant>
</spells>
```

python code proposition

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('D:\\desktop\\Archivos\\compilaciones\\1.5\\800\\data\\spells\\spells.xml')
root = tree.getroot()




for i in root.findall('instant'):
    name_spells = i.get('name')
    value_name_vocation = i.find('.//vocation[last()]')
   
    print(name_spells, value_name_vocation)
```

**Output Problem**(<Element 'vocation' at 0x000001C9C7849040>)

```
spells1 <Element 'vocation' at 0x000001C9C7AB9810>
spells2 <Element 'vocation' at 0x000001C9C7849040>
```

**desirable output**

```
spells1 men 100
spells2 woman 100
```

I was searching and some functions don't work.

```
.text -> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
          ->'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iter'
```

I am open to using other libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the element object already you just need to get its name from within it. Like you already do with your counter variable `i`.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('D:\\desktop\\Archivos\\compilaciones\\1.5\\800\\data\\spells\\spells.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


for i in root.findall('instant'):
    name_spells = i.get('name')
    value_name_vocation = i.find('.//vocation[last()]')
   
    print(name_spells, value_name_vocation.get('name'))
```